# determine that an instance has GetHashCode and Equals overridden?

Tags: c#, .net, equality

Given an instance of an object in C#, how can I determine if that object has value semantics? In other words, I want to guarantee that an object used in my API is suitable to be used as a dictionary key. I was thinking about something like this:

```
var type = instance.GetType();
var d1 = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);
var d2 = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);
Assert.AreEqual(d1.GetHashCode(), d2.GetHashCode());
```

What do you think of that approach?

Comment: You could make a generic constraint based on `IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: A type with the default reference equality is very suitable for a Dictionary key.

Comment: Easier: `instance.GetHashCode() == RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(instance)`. It tells if the returned hash code is the same as the one the non-overridden `object` implementation uses. It is not too meaningful for value types, though, but should work (hash code of a new box). Note that the hash codes being identical could be an "accident" (by chance).

Comment: @HenkHolterman True; but you would need the very same object to retrieve the value. It is unlikely to help in most of the cases.

Comment: I think this is a problem you should be trying to solve with documentation rather than reflection. You should make clear to consuming parties that you expect something that properly implements hashing and equatability, and that should be that.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to make mistakes unlikely or do you want a guarantee (that's impossible)?

Comment: Suppose you did get this to work. Now suppose the user of your API decides that reference equality *is* sensible for the specific use case. (Like, say, if objects come from a repository, where that repository makes sure never to emit "duplicate" objects.) Suppose that user works around your artificial limitation with `class A { public override Equals(object other) { return base.Equals(other); } public override int GetHashCode() { return base.GetHashCode(); } }`. Now suppose the next developer sees that these overrides are useless and removes them. Things break. Who gets the blame? You do.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I quite like your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` can put the object in an invalid state; It breaks the guaranteed assignment of readonly fields etc. Any code which assumes that fields will not be `null` will break. I wouldn't use that.

You can check whether `GetHashCode` and `Equals` is overridden via reflection, but that's not enough. You could override the method call base class method. That doesn't count as value semantics.

Btw value semantics doesn't mean equal hashcodes. It could be a collision too; Value semantics means that two objects with equals properties should return same hashcode as well as equals method should evaluate to true.

I suggest you to create an instance, assign some properties, clone it; Now both hashcodes should be equal and calling `object.Equals(original, clone)` should evaluate to true.

Comment: I agree with all of your answer, but I wanted to highlight that creating an instance, assigning some properties, cloning, and then comparing hashcodes is unreliable. Depending on how the hashcode is implemented, a broken implementation could still behave correctly for some hashcodes (and if you're unlucky, those are the ones you will end up testing).

Comment: @Asad Good point; If the implementation of hashcode is broken, then OP should fix that before writing this method. Also I'm not sure whether writing this test is a sensible thing to do. When he decides to add a type as the key to the dictionary, he can make sure the type has value semantics. IMO no need a test for this. We do this all the time and never written a test for checking value semantics.

Comment: OP is trying to test whether some consumer of their API has implemented value semantics correctly in a type they're passing as a type argument to OP's code. I don't think there is any way for OP to fix it if it is broken. My point is that there is no foolproof way for OP to even detect whether hashing is properly implemented, so it is better to just state in the documentation, "implement hashing and equatability, or else", and leave it at that.

Comment: Thanks for the good discussion. I'll definitely be including the requirements in the API documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can test for implementation of `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` with this:

```
s.GetType().GetMethod("GetHashCode").DeclaringType == s.GetType()
```

or rather per @hvd's suggestion:

```
s.GetType().GetMethod("GetHashCode").DeclaringType != typeof(object)
```

Some some object s, if `GetHashCode()` is not implemented by it's type, this will be false, otherwise true.

One thing to be careful on is that this will not protect against a poor implementation of `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()` - this would evaluate to true even if the implementation was `public override int GetHashCode() { }`.

Given the drawbacks, I would tend towards documenting your types ("this type should / should not be used for a dictionary key..."), because this isn't something you could ultimately depend upon. If the implementation of `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()` was flawed instead of missing, it would pass this test but still have a run-time error.

Comment: You probably want `!= typeof(object)`, not `== s.GetType()`. A different base class may override the method in a sensible way already.

Comment: @hvd It's a good thought, though doesn't that trade one "maybe situation" for another?

Comment: Yeah, and I already commented on the question why I think the OP should give up on this approach entirely. :) But if the OP wants to go for it anyway, I think treating base class overrides as probably having value semantics is closer in line with what the OP asks for.

Comment: I see what you're saying there.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if an object defines its own `Equals` and `GetHashCode` using the `DeclaringType` property on the corresponding `MethodInfo`:

```
bool definesEquality = type.GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(object) }).DelcaringType == type && type.GetMethod("GetHashCode", Type.EmptyTypes).DeclaringType == type;
```

Comment: That doesn't count as value semantics. Overridden method could call the base implementation simply(which could be using reference comparison).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Yes, this only answers the question in the title.